# Tray Icon issue

Tags: visual-c++, trayicon, popup-balloons

i have a program which displays tray icon and popups and balloon when some event occurs. The problem arises when i change the image of the try icon no balloon popups when the event occurs what could i be missing?

Abdul khaliq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe when you're changing the icon, its `ICONDATA` gets modified in a way that the system won't show the balloon or modify the notification icon anymore. It could be even incorrectly set `cbSize` struct member.

Check if `Shell_NotifyIcon` returns `TRUE` when trying to pop up. If `FALSE`, also check the dwMessage member, whether it's set to e.g. `NIM_SETVERSION`. That could mean that the `ICONDATA` structure's version given is unsupported, like the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159%28VS.85%29.aspx) says.

Also in case of a failure check the actual error with the `GetLastError` function.

Comment: ok i resolved the issue to some extent, the baloon does not shows up on some pcs event if the Shell_NotifyIcon() methog return true. what can be the problem

Comment: What are those PCs' Windows versions as opposed to those where balloons show up?

Comment: Windows xp version 5.1 build 2600 sp3